# Highlighting label on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm creating an app that, as an mp3 file reads some text, I should highlight the text as it is being read. I can think of a certain way to do it but it seems a bit tedious and probably not the best way to go about doing it. My idea is manually timing each word and then highlight it at a certain point. I'm not sure if thats the best/only way to do it? Anyone know of any frameworks or open source projects that could help with this problem? Or any advice on how to go about doing this.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 
`labelWithTheCompleteText` is a `UILabel` with your complete text
`wordJustRead` is the word which is read

The below code has to be called when ever a word is read by your mp3 file.

```
//appending a blank space assuming that a blank space will follow after each word
NSString *stringToBeHighlighted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",   wordJustRead];
NSMutableAttributedString *anAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringToBeHighlighted];
[anAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, anAttributedString.length)];
labelWithTheCompleteText.attributedText = anAttributedString;
```

Hope this Helps you out.. i Have not tried this out but if you can find out which word was read by your mp3file.. this should work. :)